# systemd-mount: find mount details given mountpoint

Tags: systemd, automounting

How do I find out what `systemd` wants to mount on an `autofs` mount point?

For example, if I have `/media/backup` mounted by `systemd-mount`:

```
$ grep backup /proc/mounts 
systemd-1 /media/backup autofs rw,relatime,fd=33,pgrp=1,timeout=30,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct 0 0
```

How do I find out *before automounting* what will be used for:

- Source (device / label / UUID) (`fs_spec`)
- Filesystem type (`fs_vfstype`)
- Mount options (`fs_mntops`)
- Dump (`fs_freq`)
- `fsck` order (`fs_passno`)

Comment: Systemd will check /etc/fstab as well as /lib/systemd/system/*.automount and /usr/lib/systemd/system/*.automount for automount information.

Comment: @RamanSailopal Thanks, I want to know what it's final result is... Is it possible to create an automount from the command line which doesn't create an entry in either of those 3 locations?

Comment: Is there a reason why `systemctl cat $(systemd-escape -p /media/backup --suffix=mount)` doesn't work?

Comment: @sourcejedi That does the trick. I'm still a noob when it comes to `systemd`. Does `systemd` always use `0 0` for the last 2 fields? Make and answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Ah, I was surprised because I remembered you showing me `systemd-escape`, I didn't stop to think that you might not have seen `systemctl cat` :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
systemctl cat "$(systemd-escape -p /media/backup --suffix=mount)"
```

It looks like passno information (which is treated as a boolean only) gets encoded as a Requires depedency on a `systemd-fsck`... service.